# my output is right alignment in default using pandas read_csv option

Tags: python, pandas

I have using the below python pandas code to read a csv file but the output is not proper and its default right alignment

Input:

```
Name,Age,Income
Rob, 24,4521
Siva,34,54821
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/vpitcs9/income.csv")
df
```

Actual output:

```
Name;Age;Income($)
0   Rob;27;80000
1   Mic;26;80000
2   Krithik;10;170000
```

Expected output:

```
  Name  Age   Income($)
0  Rob   27   80000
1  Mic   26   80000
2  Krithik 10 17000
```

Kindly someone help on this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the input delimiter is not `,` and `;` instead.

Try using

```py
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/vpitcs9/income.csv", sep=';')
```